Atomic term symbol with a letter prefix
I was wondering if someone could answer a question about atomic term symbols as they appear in NIST. I'm looking, for instance, at the symbols for the ground state of singly-ionised iron (Fe+/Fe II) at 1256.6769 nm (accessed through this link)
I understand the components
Configuration = 3d6(5D)4s, Term=6D, J=9/2
but the Term has the symbol "a" in front of it - I've also seen b, u, x, y, z etc. Can anyone explain what these symbols mean? This transition is written in publications as
a6D9/2–a4D7/2

Thanks, but those references just have the same symbols. This seems to be for Fe in particular. Other elements do not. I've seem e.g. y^7P in other puublications for excited states.

In diatomic and polyatomic electronic spectroscopy, X labels the ground state and then A, B, etc. successively higher excited states with the same spin multiplicity as the ground state. Lower case a, b, etc. are excited states of different multiplicity to the ground state. Not sure if that applies to atomic states.

It is indeed in reference to excited states for Fe as noted by @dharr - see the publication (Nave and Johansson) linked in the page you linked.
